# memcached fails after running for a while

Tags: python, django, docker, memcached

I am using Django with memcached with somewhat high volume of requests.
At first the memcached works fine, however, after a while it starts raising errors from time to time. The error messages are also inconsistent. After spending a lot of time I can't even find out what exactly the errors mean, nor how to resolve it.

Setup:

- Django + default memcached backend
- memcached is started using Docker: 
  `docker up -d memcached -m 3072m -I 10m -c 4096`
- memcached uses its own dedicated host
- Host spec: 4 CPU + 3.5GB ram
- swappiness = 0
- running on Google compute engine

Stats

```
 stats
    STAT pid 1
    STAT uptime 38718
    STAT time 1476576775
    STAT version 1.4.31
    STAT libevent 2.0.21-stable
    STAT pointer_size 64
    STAT rusage_user 73.432000
    STAT rusage_system 565.536000
    STAT curr_connections 10
    STAT total_connections 346393
    STAT connection_structures 4070
    STAT reserved_fds 20
    STAT cmd_get 710031
    STAT cmd_set 373473
    STAT cmd_flush 0
    STAT cmd_touch 0
    STAT get_hits 681898
    STAT get_misses 28133
    STAT get_expired 1295
    STAT get_flushed 0
    STAT delete_misses 0
    STAT delete_hits 0
    STAT incr_misses 0
    STAT incr_hits 0
    STAT decr_misses 0
    STAT decr_hits 0
    STAT cas_misses 0
    STAT cas_hits 0
    STAT cas_badval 0
    STAT touch_hits 0
    STAT touch_misses 0
    STAT auth_cmds 0
    STAT auth_errors 0
    STAT bytes_read 294333584541
    STAT bytes_written 294114029877
    STAT limit_maxbytes 3221225472
    STAT accepting_conns 1
    STAT listen_disabled_num 8604
    STAT time_in_listen_disabled_us 207162898
    STAT threads 4
    STAT conn_yields 0
    STAT hash_power_level 16
    STAT hash_bytes 524288
    STAT hash_is_expanding 0
    STAT malloc_fails 0
    STAT log_worker_dropped 0
    STAT log_worker_written 0
    STAT log_watcher_skipped 0
    STAT log_watcher_sent 0
    STAT bytes 80025379
    STAT curr_items 4616
    STAT total_items 373473
    STAT expired_unfetched 20032
    STAT evicted_unfetched 0
    STAT evictions 0
    STAT reclaimed 21994
    STAT crawler_reclaimed 0
    STAT crawler_items_checked 0
    STAT lrutail_reflocked 1229
    END
```

Different Error Messages

```
Exception Value: error 31 from memcached_get(:1:a7735b06da00d2e6991920299c31): (14006136669712) A TIMEOUT OCCURRED, host: 10.140.0.16:11211 -> libmemcached/get.cc:314

error 37 from memcached_set: SUCCESS

error 47 from memcached_get(:1:throttle_naive_9885206_None_): (140085126390144) SERVER HAS FAILED AND IS DISABLED UNTIL TIMED RETRY, host: 10.140.0.16:11211 -> libmemcached/get.cc:314
```

Note

- In all cases, it seems the memcached docker is still functional as
  `stats` still works and not all requests generates error
- CPU usage for memcached host is around 1% only
- I used to have the same problem when having the memcached instance on the same host as my frontend service. However, the same problem.

EDIT: As I was not able to solve this problem, I switched to Redis on the same host. Although I didn't get it right at the first time, Redis provides comprehensive error messages so I can easily resolve them. Now my cache is running stably.

Comment: A brute suggestion, but I'll ask it - have you had take a look into memcached code (documentation at least) ? 
Couldn't it be just simply cache misses first place ?.
Doesn't seems to be the case, but...

Comment: Docker does provides me with hours of entertainment every other update usually. Retracing latest updates and looking into what has changed may provide you some hint as well

Comment: Yes I did. I have searched through the source code and the documents. Found multiple documents on how to set it up, and also the error code table in the source code. However, I have trouble understanding what the error message mean when it says something like 'SUCCESS'. Cache miss doesn't raise errors, but just return None. Note that it doesn't raise error until running for a while. I uses the latest official docker image. More input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As for me, you should proceed with reviewing (analysis) the code for  particular error codes (37, 47, as in your report). Reducing to some reproducible test case meanwhile
It looks like your network (or the host you're running memcached at) has some serious errors...
Cannot say what the exact reason of it so far though.
Sorry I cannot suggest you anything better, that's a vector I'd follow myself in this case at least.
Mentioning to review system logs is obvious, I suppose